# Cross-Domain IndexedDB Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, nosql, indexeddb

I'm new to indexedDB and my goal is to create a chrome extension that keeps track of all SSO pages and their redirects. My idea is to store each sign-in link and their respective redirects in a tree; however, indexedDB creates a new database for each link that i visit, so i'm having trouble making the tree. Is there any way around this?

'''

```
// Record variables to be used for indexedDB
let request = window.indexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase", 2),
  db,
  tx,
  store,
  index;

// triggered when a database of a bigger version number than the existing stored database is loaded
request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
  let db = request.result,
    store = db.createObjectStore("URL", { autoIncrement: true }),
    index = store.createIndex("link no.", "URL", { unique: false });
};

// triggered if the database cannot load
request.onerror = function (e) {
  console.log("The database 'linkStorage' could not be opened");
};

/* triggered if it does load

    - open a transaction, define the object store ("URL")
    - creates an index for data retrieval
    - append the current link to indexedDB, console.log it, and print the index
*/
request.onsuccess = function (e) {
  db = request.result;
  (tx = db.transaction("URL", "readwrite")),
    (store = tx.objectStore("URL")),
    store.index("link no.");

  db.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("ERROR could not open db" + e.target.errorCode);
  };

  var link = window.location.href;
  store.put(link);

  var countRequest = store.count();
  countRequest.onsuccess = function () {
    var count = countRequest.result;
    var lastLink = store.get(count);
    lastLink.onsuccess = function () {
      console.log("Index = " + count);
      console.log("Current link = " + lastLink.result);
    };
  };

  tx.oncomplete = function () {
    db.close();
  };
};
```

'''

Comment: You need to do send the data from the content script in a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and process it in  the background script that uses IndexedDB of the extension's origin.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit? I don't exactly understand how i can do this

Comment: Show your current [MCVE](/help/mcve), see also the [intro](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/) that explains the concepts.

Comment: just added my script for adding links. pls let me know and thank you so much

Comment: 1) Replace `2` with `1` in indexedDB.open or remove it altogether. 2) Is this the content script? If so, use my comments above to learn about messaging, background scripts, and so on. Your content script will send location.href to the background script. There, in chrome.runtime.onMessage listener you will store the url from the message in IndexedDB. 3) Alternatively you can use chrome.storage.local in your content sccript instead of IndexedDB.